# Deliyannis-type narrowband filter is oscillating when I apply GND to the input

Tags: active-filter, oscillation

TLTR: My Deliyannis-type narrowband filter is oscillating when I apply GND to the input Vin. I was expecting to get almost zero volts, but I am actually getting a sine wave at almost 20KHz. I´m trying to figure out how to debug. I pretty sure something is wrong here.

I am currently working in an acoustic application for which I built an active filter with a unique opamp: narrow band type centered around 40KHz. I based my design on a cookbook called “Filter design in 30 seconds” from Texas Instruments, [which can be found here](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa093/sloa093.pdf). The basic scheme is this:

[image]

According to recipe, to get the filter centered on 40KHz, I need: R1=4K, R3=77K, R4=4K, R2=50, C1=C2=1nF. **EDIT**: The recipe is here:

[image]

**EDIT**: the teorical value of R2 is 210omhs, but in AC small signal simulation I saw that only achieved the peak at 30KHz, so I played with it until I got the current value of 50. I am unsure if this modification is recommended.

I soldered the circuit in one of those perfboard (I have yet to get a CNC machine to build PCBs).

Used non polarity capacitors and precision resistors (except for R3 where I soldered two 38K resistors in series).

I bought a few 741 ICs from different brand. I am feeding the circuit with bipolar +-5V, using rechargeable batteries.

I added two 100nF decoupling capacitors between -+VCC and GND.

I added potentiometer fed with -Vcc to cancel the offset. I am using a Hantek 6022 USB oscilloscope to graph the output and voltmeter to check continuity.

I haven’t used the waveform generator to test it with different frequency inputs, because I am on weekend and have to wait until Tuesday to go to laboratory to get access to generator.

Meanwhile I am testing the circuit by applying GND to the input Vin, and I get SINE noise at the output.

WHY IS THIS HAPPENING?

I checked different new ICs and all of them showed similar response.

I simulated the circuit with the theoretical values.

This is LTSPICE freq response for frequency sweep (gain) can be seen:

[image]

So I think in theory this should work.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**: I simulated the circuit with a TL072 instead of 741 and found that the peak is reached at much higher freqnecy now (58KHz). So R2 needs to be adjusted to 150ohms now, to make it work.

**EDIT**: I simulated transitory response of the circuit, feeding the input with a 3 series combination of sine signals: 1KHz + 60Hz + 40KHz (amplitude=0.01). I see that 60Hz/1KHz noise is gone, so its actually filtering.

The purpose of this circuit is filter out any frequency other than 40Khz that comes from an ultrasonic microphone. When measured the microphone by itself with a stimulus signal of 40KHz, I can see noise at different frequencies: 60Hz, 4KHz, etc. I need something simple that allows me this. Have tried a lot of differents schemes in breadboard but none of them ever worked (I guess because of parasitic capacitances).

I am open to test a new filter if I figure out that this is an unappropiate selection. I think that I need a passing frequency of 40KHz with a 5KHz maximum bandwidth. About the Q factor, Im unsure and listen to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried running a `.TRAN` analysis (with `uic`)? I am getting oscillations, though damped. `.AC` analysis will not tell you about temporal behaviour (also, don't get cheap with number of points/dec, `.AC` goes very fast). My guess is's the perfboard that's causing various parasitics to go against you -- mostly inductances due to wires.

Comment: You will have no success using 741 type amplifiers for frequencies above 10 kHz. This is due to the limited slew rate (large-signal bandwidth app. 10k only).

Comment: \$ R_2 = 50 \, \Omega \$? I find that hard to believe. If \$ R_2 = 50 \, k\Omega \$, 'supplying ground to the input' is almost the same as short circuiting \$ R_2 \$ with \$ R_1 \$. Your filter's characteristics will change radically if \$ R_2 \$ effectively is lowered by a factor more than \$ 10 \$.

Comment: [Why not to use the 741.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304521/reasons-not-to-use-a-741-op-amp/304522)

Comment: R3 and R4 look strange. If there are no other connections to them, then it would make sense to combine them into one.  Since they are seperate, I expect there ought to be something connected to the junction of R3 and R4.  Could you check the original "recipe" circuit?

Comment: @JRE - I've edited to include a link to the TI design guide. The circuit is designed around a Q of 10 and a gain of 10. The guide doesn't give the underlying design equations, so I can't verify the appropriateness of the selection.

Comment: Ok.  It makes sense if you see the description.  When you build it, you can combine them into one.  They are seperated for the calculations.

Comment: Thanks guys. I checked your feedback and additional information was added to original question

Comment: For equations for Q and fc refer to page 8, sec. 4.1 of TI literature SLOA096
[1]: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa096/sloa096.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the shown circuit some comments are necessary. Without re-calculating the parts values (not possible because of uncomplete filter specification) I did some simulation runs based on your parts values.

Results:

Opamp LF356: Midfrequency fo=67 kHz.

Opamp LM741: Midfrequency fo=39 kHz.

What does this mean? The midfrequency of the bandpass is not determined by the external feedback elements only but also by the real opamp gain characteristic (in particular, unwanted additional phase shift). This is, of course, no surprise because the frequency characteristics of the 741-type opamp is not sufficient for realizing a 40kHz bandpass.

As a consequence, a redesign of the circuit is necessary based on a clear specification (bandwidth, Q-Value, gain requirements?) and a high-frequency opamp with a sufficient slew rate. In this context, one should realize that an ac analysis is a small-signal analysis which cannot reveal slew rate problems.

**EDIT/UPDATE**

Your calculation of R2 seems to be false. The correct value is R2=210 ohms. In this case and using the LM741 model, the center frequency is app. at 30 kHz. Using another opamp model (TL072) with a much larger gain-bandwidth product, the desired value of 40kHz can be achieved with good accuracy.

Comment: I edited the original question, to explain that I changed the R2=210 to 50ohms, because simulation didnt achieve the passband at 40KHz and I thought that fine-tunning was required. I then simulated the circuit with a different OPAMP (TL072) and saw your same results. So the opamp is limiting the frequency instead of the external components. with TL072, I need to set R2=150 to achieve 40KHz. Something still wrong.

Comment: BTW, I appretiate the time u took to help.

Comment: With R2=150, R1=4k and R3+R4=81k my simulation results for the TL072 model are 32kHz. Only with R2=210 Ohm I achieved 40kHz.

Comment: I can't exactly reproduce ur results. Still get 40KHz for R2=150, if I change it for R2=210, I instead get 35KHz. I am using the TL072 downloaded from "http://www.ti.com/product/TL072". I wonder if we are using the same model or a different configuration.

Comment: You are right - for 210 ohms the peak frequency  is app. 35kHz (TL072). Only for an IDEAL opamp we achieve 40kHz . That means: TL072 is still not good enough for your purpose because the bandpass should be independent on the opamp used (TL072 at 40kHz has an open-loop gain of Aol=40dB only.). You need an opamp with a gain-bandwidth product of at least 6 MHz.

Comment: Well, I think I can now try something different. I will drop by the store and grab a few chips, will tell you what happens later :)

Answer (score 0):

Dudes, after simulating, checking datasheets, and reading ur suggestions, I swaped the IC to the best opamp I could get: TL071, which BW is 3MHz. The SPICE simulation shows a peak at 40Khz, with Gain = 7 = 17dB. The components are: Conditions: R1=4K, R2=250, R3=50K, R4=4K, C1=C2=1nF.

In a live test with a square wave (f=40KHz), it filters well and has a Gain = 3 = 9dB.
Probably behaving this way because of BW limitation of the real IC. I wish I could use a better one like LF356/357.

[image]

By now, I would consider this SOLVED.